# How can I get a list of all possible matches in between non-greedy and greedy

Tags: python, regex, greedy, non-greedy

I have the string `"I like lettuce and carrots and onions"` in Python.

I thought I could get the following matches `["I like lettuce", "I like lettuce and carrots", "I like lettuce and carrots and onions"]` by using a regex like `.* and`. (The regex should match any character up to " and".)

However, using the greedy version (`.* and`) gives me only the last match, and using the non-greedy version (`.*? and`) gives me only the first match.

How can I get all three matches?

(I do not need a regex solution.)

Comment: @user202729 I'm not quite seeing how that could help. If you could post a quick comment with a solution from that page, that would be great. The overlapping solution is not giving me what I wanted; I haven't tried the other one yet.

Comment: Right... in this case the matches have the same match index (position of first match character).

Comment: Looks like the answers below need some word boundary.

Comment: My minimal working example was a bit too simple. The actual code I'm working with requires something that has more than just one unknown, so the regex might look something like `I like (.*) and (.*) because (.*)` in the string `"I like lettuce and carrots and onions and dressing because I do."` and I want back `["I like (lettuce and carrots) and (onions) because (I do)", "I like (lettuce) and (carrots and onions) because (I do)"]`. I think I will post a new question to address this.

Comment: New question has been posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50341789/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-words-in-a-string-with-specified-fixed-w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fun, use the string `partition` method in Python 3.  It searches a string for a substring, and returns a 3-tuple.  When there's a match, it's

> (string before the match, the match, string after the match)

Once you're used to it, it's very pleasant - no indexing needed, and it makes it easy to get the right results.  So while this code is longer than some other ways, you should be able to reason about it easily:

```
def findallprefix(s, sep):
    sofar = ""
    while True:
        head, matched, s = s.partition(sep)
        if matched:
            assert matched == sep
            sofar += head
            yield sofar
            sofar += matched
        else:
            break

s = "I like lettuce and carrots and onions and dressing."
for match in findallprefix(s, " and"):
    print(repr(match))
```

which prints

```
'I like lettuce'
'I like lettuce and carrots'
'I like lettuce and carrots and onions'
```

Comment: The partition function is exactly the type of thing I was looking for. You may want to answer [the question I was trying to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50342462/how-to-find-matches-around-fixed-strings)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use an re at all: What is wrong with:

```
p = "I like lettuce and carrots and onions and dressing.".split("and")
```

which gives you a list from which you construct the desired strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple splitting and construct strings without an expensive `regex`:

```
s = "I like lettuce and carrots and onions and dressing."

splitted = s.split('and')
for x in range(1, len(splitted)):
    print('and'.join(splitted[:x]))

# I like lettuce
# I like lettuce and carrots                                  
# I like lettuce and carrots and onions
```

If you need result in a list, go for a list-comprehension:

```
>>> s = "I like lettuce and carrots and onions and dressing."
>>> splitted = s.split('and')
>>> ['and'.join(splitted[:x]) for x in range(1, len(splitted))]
['I like lettuce ', 'I like lettuce and carrots ', 'I like lettuce and carrots and onions ']
```